# parsing json array with in the array through GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I am new in android though I am facing problem in parsing json array with in the array.

```
{
"menu": [
    {
        "Soups": [
            {
                "name": "Safed Tamatar aur Tulsi ",
                "price": 150,
                "description": "",
                "veg": true,
                "spicy": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Dum Murg",
                "price": 168,
                "description": "",
                "veg": false,
                "spicy": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Murg Zaffrani",
                "price": 168,
                "description": "",
                "veg": false,
                "spicy": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Tomato Dhania",
                "price": 150,
                "description": "",
                "veg": true,
                "spicy": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Starters": [
            {
                "name": "Achari Paneer tikka",
                "price": 347,
                "description": "",
                "veg": true,
                "spicy": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Paneer Tikka",
                "price": 347,
                "description": "",
                "veg": true,
                "spicy": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Murg Tikka",
                "price": 393,
                "description": "",
                "veg": false,
                "spicy": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Tandoori Murg (Half)",
                "price": 410,
                "description": "",
                "veg": false,
                "spicy": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Tandoori Murg (Full)",
                "price": 851,
                "description": "",
                "veg": false,
                "spicy": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Macchi Tikka",
                "price": 626,
                "description": "",
                "veg": false,
                "spicy": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Main Course": [
            {
                "name": "Jeera Aloo",
                "price": 275,
                "description": "",
                "veg": true,
                "spicy": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Paneer Tikka Masala",
                "price": 392,
                "description": "",
                "veg": true,
                "spicy": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Palak Paneer",
                "price": 370,
                "description": "",
                "veg": true,
                "spicy": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Murg Kadhai",
                "price": 428,
                "description": "",
                "veg": false,
                "spicy": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Murg Tikka Masala",
                "price": 428,
                "description": "",
                "veg": false,
                "spicy": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Palak Gosht",
                "price": 455,
                "description": "",
                "veg": false,
                "spicy": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Macchi Kadhai",
                "price": 545,
                "description": "",
                "veg": false,
                "spicy": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Rice": []
    },
    {
        "Breads": []
    },
    {
        "Accompaniments": []
    },
    {
        "Beverages": []
    },
    {
        "Dessert": []
    },
    {
        "Signature Mocktails": []
    },
    {
        "Wraps": []
    },
    {
        "Lentils": [
            {
                "name": "Dal Tadka",
                "price": 226,
                "description": "",
                "veg": true,
                "spicy": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Dal Kolhapuri",
                "price": 226,
                "description": "",
                "veg": true,
                "spicy": null
            },
            {
                "name": "Dal Makhani",
                "price": 275,
                "description": "",
                "veg": true,
                "spicy": null
            }
        ]
    }
    ],
    "name": "Zaffran"
}
```

I want to parse this file, but there is no such code on internet to parse this file through GSON.
I used following code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("menu");
        String jsonString = jsonArray.toString();
        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {
        }.getType();
        Map<String, String> myMap = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
            key = entry.getKey();
            value = entry.getValue();
            // do stuff
        }
        responseView.setText(value);
```

But, It gives error that String expected found array. Please help me

Comment: This will help  you.https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html & http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/how-to-parsing-json-array-using-gson-in-android-tutorial/

Comment: thanks for helping me , but i tried one of your link but seems it is not working either, it gives the following error:  Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 10-  @SuhasB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to parse your full json data.

```
  try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonArray);

        JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("menu");
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        if (jsonObject.has("name")) {
            menu.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
        } else {
            menu.setName("");
        }
        List<MenuHeaders> menuHeadersList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray1.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
            MenuHeaders menuHeaders = new MenuHeaders();
            //Creating list to save all prices and item names
            List<ItemDetails> list = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray subHeaderJsonArray = null;

            if (jsonObject1.has("Soups")) {
                menuHeaders.setTitle("Soups");
                subHeaderJsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("Soups");
            }
            if (jsonObject1.has("Starters")) {
                menuHeaders.setTitle("Starters");
                subHeaderJsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("Starters");

            }
            if (jsonObject1.has("Main Course")) {
                menuHeaders.setTitle("Main Course");
                subHeaderJsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("Main Course");
            }
            if (jsonObject1.has("Rice")) {
                menuHeaders.setTitle("Rice");
                subHeaderJsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("Rice");
            }
            if (jsonObject1.has("Breads")) {
                menuHeaders.setTitle("Breads");
                subHeaderJsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("Breads");
            }
            if (jsonObject1.has("Accompaniments")) {
                menuHeaders.setTitle("Accompaniments");
                subHeaderJsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("Accompaniments");
            }
            //Add all other sub menu items to menu object

            if (jsonObject1.has("Lentils")) {
                menuHeaders.setTitle("Lentils");
                subHeaderJsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("Lentils");
            }
            if (subHeaderJsonArray != null) {
                for (int index1 = 0; index1 < subHeaderJsonArray.length(); index1++) {
                    JSONObject subHeaderJsonObject = subHeaderJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    ItemDetails itemDetails = new ItemDetails();
                    itemDetails.setName(subHeaderJsonObject.getString("name"));
                    itemDetails.setPrice(subHeaderJsonObject.getInt("price"));
                    itemDetails.setDescription(subHeaderJsonObject.getString("description"));
                    itemDetails.setVeg(subHeaderJsonObject.getBoolean("veg"));
                    itemDetails.setSpicy(subHeaderJsonObject.getString("spicy"));
                    list.add(itemDetails);
                }
                menuHeaders.setList(list);
            }
            menuHeadersList.add(menuHeaders);
            menu.setMenuHeaders(menuHeadersList);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Ya ..its working , but problem is that I need to parse this  data in array form without knowing the name of internal Arrays eg: Soups , Starter, etc

Comment: No..Without knowing string, you cannot parse. Anywayz you the titles and data you are getting ..right? Then why don't you use this code to parse.

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect answer but I have tried to show you the format of parsing nested json. This will give you json array "Menu" and its inner arrays also.

Change it according to your need.

```
    JSONObject jsonMenu = mJsonObject.optJSONObject("menu");

                JSONArray jsnSoupsarr = jsonMenu.optJSONArray("Soups");
                for (int k = 0; k < jsnSoupsarr.length(); k++) {
                    JSONObject jsnSoup = jsnMSouparr.optJSONObject(k);
                    //here get the  inner fields of "Soup" like "price","name" etc.
                }

                JSONArray startersJson = jsnMenu.optJSONArray("Starters");
                for (int k = 0; k < starterJson.length(); k++) {
                    JSONObject objstarter = starterJson.optJSONObject(k);
                }

                JSONArray mainCourseJson = jsnMenu.optJSONArray("Main Course");
                for (int k = 0; k < mainCourseJson.length(); k++) {
                    JSONObject objmainCourse = mainCourseJson.optJSONObject(k);}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ya ..its working , but problem is that this menu  is not a static entity. Basically, menu gives the general from for any restaurant . It is not necessary to have all these things, may be there is alternate variety of these cuisine, so i need to parse this  data in array form without knowing the name of internal Arrays...  -@Suhas B

Comment: If you don't want to parse with names you can get it by positions. Like take **for loop** for **Menu** array and use `jsonMenu.optJSONArray(i)` in that for loop like we did in inner arrays for **soups** and **starters** .